# Spring 4.3.0 + Tomcat : "Failed to load resource " message for static files

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC with AngularJS as the frontend.
Unfortunately, I can't see the static files when deploying in Tomcat.

My aim is to deploy the AngularJS frontend files and the Spring backend stuff all together as a single WAR file for deployment in Tomcat.

I don't want to use JSP nor Spring XML files.

This is the structure of my Eclipse Maven folder :

[Structure of webapp folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK5Kh.png)

My index.html file contains the following entries :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>

<link href="bower_components/angular-xeditable/dist/css/xeditable.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
```

My SpringConfig.java looks like this :

```
 @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     registry.addResourceHandler("/bower_components/**").addResourceLocations("/bower_components").setCachePeriod(3600);
     registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js");
  }


 @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
```

I hope someone can help me out !

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just an issue with your slashes. Try this:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addResourceHandler("bower_components/**").addResourceLocations("/bower_components/").setCachePeriod(3600);
  registry.addResourceHandler("js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
}
```

If that doesn't work, you may have to fiddle with it. No one knows why it is like that, but unfortunately URL path pattern matching has been one of the most inconsistent and buggiest aspects of Spring MVC for years.